# Как установить torchtext в проект cmake c++?

Tags: c++, cmake, pytorch

Как установить torchtext в проект cmake c++? Никак не могу понять

Comment: Покажите вашу попытку, и ошибки, которые получили.

Comment: Сначала просто пытался установить через pip и затем прописать find_package, естественно ошибка, затем пытался скачать исходник с гитхаба и указать путь до него, ошибка, затем последнее - это пытался сбилдить с гитхаба - тоже ошибка

Comment: Стоит libtorch debug version cpu последняя версия

Comment: Покажите что конкретно вы делали, какие команды запускали, и полный текст ошибки (отдельно на каждую вещь, которую вы пробовали).

Comment: Сейчас, к сожалению, не могу точно сказать какие были ошибки, буду свободен только завтра часов в 6-7 и скажу конкретный текст

Comment: FAILED: third_party/sentencepiece/src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/arena.cc.obj при попытке сбилдить проект самостоятельно

Comment: Прочитайте мой последний комментарий еще раз.

Comment: Во-первых, просто в консоли прописал: pip install torch torchtext, после установки прописывал в файл CMakeLists.txt строчку: find_package(TorchText REQUIRED) и выдаёт ошибку: CMake did not find one. Could not find a package configuration file provided by "TorchText" with any of the following names: TorchTextConfig.cmake torchtext-config.cmake .

Comment: `pip` ставит только версию для питона, как я понимаю. А самостоятельно какой командой собирали?

Comment: Для начала chmod build.sh
Затем просто build.sh
/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory
С помощью установлениой  подсистемы Ubuntu

Comment: Попробуйте склонировать код заново, на WSL. Этот вы похоже склонировали на винде и перенесли в WSL, поэтому там плохие (виндовые) окончания строк.

Comment: Сейчас сделал как вы сказали, уже пошли проценты: Build files have been written to, жду завершения выполнения

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144791/discussion-between-romalik-normalik-and-holyblackcat).

Comment: Сбилдилось. а как теперь импортировать в Cmakelists.txt проекта своего?

Comment: А вот тут не знаю...

Comment: Просто пишет, что не найден файл Torchtextconfig.cmake